# Vaadin 14 Flow EmailField Validation does not work

Tags: email-validation, vaadin14

Currently in Vaadin 14.6.8 the EmailField accept these values (e.g. "barney.@gmail.com", ".@gmail.com") as valid input.
Should I consider those as valid EMail Addresses ?

```
EmailField emailField = new EmailField();
```

Already searched in the net and already verified with some online email address validator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EmailField` has fairly simple regexp pattern for performance reasons to validate that input is roughly looking like e-mail. Writing complete regexp pattern to validate input against RFC 5322 is tedious task as seen in this discussion (note that complex regexp patterns are also prone to ReDoS attacks)

[How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

If you are not satisfied with `EmailField`, there is `TextField#setPattern(regexp)` method, which can be used instead of `EmailField` if you want to use more complex validation pattern. You will notice that some pragmatic compromise is needed.